# FFMPEG AVCodecContext resizes frame to match multiple of 4 bytes

Tags: ffmpeg

I am decoding video frames from FLV .The input video original size is 431x82 .Now when I am accessing the frame size from **AVCodecContext.width** and **AVCodecContext.height**  I see the sizes change to be dividable by 4 (432x96).Which probably is done internally for performance reasons.Is there a way to prevent this?